# How to process Apple Payment Token for integration with payment processor like Stripe?

Tags: python, applepay, applepay-web

Hey guys long time no see.

In [Apple Pay for iMessage](https://register.apple.com/resources/messages/msp-rest-api/type-interactive#apple-pay-message), users can initiate an Apple Pay payment on iMessage. Once the user authorizes the payment, my endpoint receives the [Apple Pay Token from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymenttoken)- this has the user's encrypted payment details. I am having trouble figuring out how to process this token to process the payment.

According to [this link](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/payment-platforms/), Stripe is authorized and is supposed to fully handle this token on their own, I would simply be forwarding the apple pay token to Stripe. Unfortunately, stripe isn't accepting the payment token as valid. I tried using the [Stripe python package](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python) and passing in the token as the 'source'  but it doesn't work.

```
 payment_intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
        amount=80,  # in cents
        currency='usd',
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        payment_method_data={
            'type': 'apple_pay',
            'apple_pay': {
                'token': ttt  # Use the Apple Pay token here
            },
        },
        confirm=True,
    )
```

Anyways, where am I going wrong here nothing else is working and I am not sure what I should do?  Do i need to do something to [de-encrypt the apple pay token](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/apple_pay/payment_token_format_reference#3949582), I am not even sure if I have the regulatory approval to do this.
P.S This is not for apple pay web or js integration.